# Myspace iPhone sdk library

Tags: myspace

Is there another library other than this one 
https://github.com/myspace/myspace-iphone-sdk
coz this one wont update status or upload media

Answer (score 0):

Please try [MySpaceIphone SDK](http://code.google.com/p/myspaceid-iphone-sdk/),

You can find more on [API page](http://developerwiki.myspace.com/index.php?title=Category%3aMySpaceID)

Comment: Hey Guys, Do you find these sdks functional..? cause i get this error every time I hit for login. "MySpaceID.Demo[17037:f803] Error occurred with RequestToken call."